# A client-side JavaScript is not defined - but it is in the HTML source. Anybody know why?

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have this function defined within my HTML source. It's in the `<body>` section, but that should be ok, right? This is how it appear in the source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
function updateL(widgetType, i) {
  var widgetParsName = "wpl:" + i; 
  if (widgetType == "youtube"){
   document.getElementById(widgetParsName).innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="30" value=""'>';
  }
  else {
   document.getElementById(widgetParsName).innerHTML = "";
  }
}
</script>
```

This should get invoked in a select using onchange:

```
<select id="wl:0" name="wl:0" onchange="updateL(this.value,0)">
```

I didn't include the entire `<select>` here because that is working. And when I select an option, the function is invoked. However nothing happens. The JavaScript Console in Chrome just reports:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: updateL is not defined"

I am stumped as to why. The script is there. I believe it's ok to have the script in the HTML body itself. I've done that before. The page is dynamically created, so I didn't want to put it in the `<head>` section where it would unnecessarily appear on every page at the site. It's only needed on this one page.

Any idea what dumb thing I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Doug

Answer (score 2):

```
... .innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="30" value=""'>';
```

This is a syntax error (bad quotes at the end). Therefore, the function is unable to be defined, and your code fails.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I stared and stared but didn't see that. However, fixing that errant ' before the bracket didn't help. I'm still getting the "Uncaught ReferenceError: updateL is not defined" error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below...

```
document.getElementById(widgetParsName).innerHTML = '<input type="text" size="30" value=""/>';
```

Comment: I've made that change as well. But unfortunately I'm still getting the same updateL is not defined error.

Comment: @DougLerner Where you have defined your function in HTML code...?

Comment: @DougLerner Can we use JQuery?

Comment: As mentioned above, the function is defined within the body section of the HTML code, not the head section. There is no "rule" which requires it be in the head section, is there? The reason I didn't want it in the head section is because that is displayed on every page at the site, and I only needed the script on this one page.

Comment: I would like to avoid jQuery because (1) this is really simple I believe and (2) I would like to avoid loading jQuery just for this one tiny thing. It seems like overkill, don't you think? This is just a simple replace of innerHtml.

Comment: @DougLerner you can check on every page by URL for call the function. To get URL see this LINK : `http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/498368/Get-current-page-URL-using-JavaScript`

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But is it required that a script be in the head section? I also hate to add an unnecessary check to every single page generated at this site (it's a forums site). So I want to avoid all extra overhead, when possible. I can't find any rule that says a script cannot be in the body section. And I have used scripts embedded in body sections before. Do you think that is the problem? Thanks?

Comment: At http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp it says: "JavaScripts can be put in the <body> and in the <head> section of an HTML page." So I don't think that is necessarily the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just another simple syntax error in the above code, involving another stray quote mark. Sorry to bother everybody. It is working now. Thanks very much for your help.